# Finding records by attribute value in a batman.js and rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, find, batman.js

I have a `User` model in my app and I would like to "find" a `User` by the `name` attribute. I don't believe there is any out-of-the-box support for this in batman.js but it is possible that it is just undocumented. I will also need to make some changes to the Rails side to receive and process this type of request as well. Has anyone already tackled this type of problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was mistaken, this functionality exists in Batman out-of-the-box.

```
YourApp.User.load({name: "wuliwong"}, (err, results) ->
  #do stuff with the results array
```

The UsersController#index action in Rails now looks like this:

```
def index
  if params[:name]
    @users = User.where(:name => params[:name])
  else
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```